# C++ Boost Filesystem: How to modify stem from a path?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I'm using the Boost Filesystem library.
I have a path

```
boost::filesystem::path P("/foo/bar.baz");
```

I want to modify the stem part of path p to "bar_quz", so path P stays

> /foo/bar_quz.baz

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to append "_quz" to the base part of the filename, or do you just want to replace it entirely?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
const std::string rndString = "quz";
boost::filesystem::path newPath = P.parent_path() / boost::filesystem::path(P.stem().string() + "_" + rndString + P.extension().string());
```

Comment: Not quite - that would end up with "/foo/bar_quz/.baz"

Comment: I think it's more "I want to append something to the filename (no matter what it is) while preserving the extension, rather than "I know exactly what I want and add an extension".  So taking a whole directory worth of files, and adding a certain thing to their filenames.  So imagine the "Base" filename as a variable too.

Comment: Yeah, Kevin is right about that. I want to append some dynamic string. Maybe this could work?

boost::filesystem::path newPath = P.parent_path() / (boost::filesystem::path(P.stem().string() + "_" + rndString ).string() + P.extension().string());